# Squish QT installation failed on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: ubuntu, squish

I'm able to install squish for qt on Ubuntu 19.10
But i'm getting below error for Ubuntu 20.04

```
$ ./squish-6.4.3-qt55x-linux64.run 
free(): invalid pointer
Aborted (core dumped)
```

## System Configuration

Virtual box - Ubuntu 20.04
Python 2 installed and configured as default

Comment: Workaround - install squish in 19.10 and then upgrade to 20.04. But this wastes ~8GB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue with the Squish installer on recent Linux distributions (triggered by an update to the `libXcb` library). You can get a new Squish build from froglogic support which doesn't exhibit this problem. Just send a mail to squish@froglogic.com.

Comment: You are right. Got a snapshot release from squish@froglogic.com.

Answer (score 0):

According to the vendor this got fixed, but requires a recent Squish 6.5 build.

Comment: No, i'm getting same error
$ ./squish-6.5.2-qt55x-linux64.run  
free(): invalid pointer  
Aborted (core dumped)

Comment: Sorry, it should be more recent than Squish 6.5.2, because this problem got fixed after this last, major release. But as I understand you have requested and received such a package by now.